# Logging SAP database updates with CDHDR change documents

Tags: logging, datatable, updates, abap, sap-basis

There is a Z table that have to be updated frequently. These updates should be tracked, and now the tracking is implemented via SAP change documents functionality.

All is working fine, records in `CDHDR` are being created, but now the `*********_WRITE_DOCUMENT` FM is called using complex logic because DB updates of are made using statement:

```
MODIFY dbtab FROM itab.
```

Where one should put `*********_WRITE_DOCUMENT` call in order to track every time MODIFY `itab` changes?
How could we simplify this procedure? How to cover all DB updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: that won't work.

Long answer: If you want't to achieve this, you have to get the information on what is changed and what is inserted yourself. I'd do an

select ...
from ZTABLE
into OLD_DATA_TAB
for all entries in ITAB
where ...

afterwards loop over ITAB and check if you have a corresponing dataset in your OLD_DATA_TAB
and if it has to be changed.

With that information you can build you input parameter for *_WRITE_DOCUMENT which you call after the successful modify, but before the commit.

Comment: It's also a good idea to encapsulate the whole load-save-revert-before_after_image-generate_change_document stuff into a class and use that instead of littering the code with database access statements. Having database modification statements distributed throughout the entire code is a sure way to run into some implicit commit issues sooner or later.

Comment: @vwegert I couldn't agree more :)

Comment: Thanks to all involved persons. Let it be) The question is closed.

Comment: Guys! Could you give me code sample of such class which is to encapsulate DB logic? I cannot realize (design) it's framework and concept.